# TextTrimming in ContentPresenter in windows store apps

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have edited the style for ListBoxItem in windows store app.
When the content of item is long I want to trim it, like in textblock we have property
    TextTrimming = "CharacterEllipsis".
I have tried it in two ways.

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
    <TextBlock TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
</ContentPresenter>
```

and

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
  <ContentPresenter.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
      <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="10"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
  </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

but not working for me, any help will appreciate.

Comment: Give maxwidth to Textblock

Comment: No, didn't work... Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, set your ListBox property `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` in XAML

Then using your first XAML example remove the `ContentPresenter` wrapping the `TextBlock` (you dont need it in this scenario) and replace with a `<Grid>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer, I tested it and it works fine. 
but I have alredy done with another scenario by editing ContentTemplate. Please check my answer and let me know which one is feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Done by editing the ContentTemplate,

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
      <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ContentPresenter, Path=Content}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        </DataTemplate>
       </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: In place of `Text="{Binding ElementName=ContentPresenter, Path=Content}"` you directly can use: `Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"`.